# Import and Display Image as a Screen in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, image, tkinter, display

I am using Visual Studio Code, Python, and Tkinter in this program and I want to import and display an image from my computer as a screen(it is in the end). I tried to import the image by copying a statement from a video example I  However, when I run the program, it says

> tkinter.TclError: bitmap "IMAGE.jpg" not defined

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

screen = Tk()
screen.iconbitmap("IMAGE.jpg")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, .jpg is not supported. Try converting it to .ico format. There are online tools, just upload your .jpg and download .ico.

Comment: Hello, I tried it and it says  return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "IMAGE.ico" not defined

Comment: I tried to recreate error and error is thrown when .ico file is not in the same folder as the .py file, otherwise it works fine and icon is placed on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I found a new solution. see this -
instead of `screen.iconbitmap("IMAGE.jpg")`
use

```
root.iconphoto(False, PhotoImage(file='IMAGE.png'))
```

**NOTE**

- Supports png only
- Import *PhotoImage* from tkinter package
- For more detail see my github repo - [here](https://github.com/Sherry65-code/Encrypter5/blob/main/main.py)